# condition in a mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a condition in my mysql query:

```
    SELECT g.* FROM groups AS g
            JOIN users AS u 
            ON u.user_posts >= g.post_min
            AND u.user_posts <= g.post_max
            AND u.points >= g.point_min
            AND u.points <= g.point_max
            AND u.uid = "'.$uid.'"
```

how should i write a condition when the g.post_max or g.point_max equal to 0  the statement dosen't need to include max values

Comment: May be this can help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT g.id,g.point_amount
            FROM groups AS g
            JOIN users AS u 
            ON u.user_posts >= g.post_min
            AND (u.user_posts <= g.post_max OR (g.post_max=0 OR g.point_max=0))
            AND u.points >= g.point_min
            AND (u.points <= g.point_max OR (g.post_max=0 OR g.point_max=0))
            AND u.uid = "'.$uid.'" 
            LIMIT 1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Join them with an OR; either the skip condition is true, OR the term can't be skipped:

```
(g.post_max = 0) OR (u.user_posts <= g.post_max)
(g.point_max = 0) OR (u.points <= g.point_max)
```

EDIT: inserting it into your query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT g.id,g.point_amount
        FROM groups AS g
        JOIN users AS u 
        ON u.user_posts >= g.post_min
        AND u.points >= g.point_min
        AND ((g.post_max = 0) OR (u.user_posts <= g.post_max))
        AND ((g.point_max = 0) OR (u.points <= g.point_max))
        AND u.uid = "'.$uid.'" 
        LIMIT 1';
```

EDIT again: I fail at reading; misunderstood your question. This is what it should look like.